# Data Hiding,Data Encapsulation? practical application

Tags: c++, oop, encapsulation

Hi I am a newbie to C++ reading the C++ concepts...............and I am unable to comprehend the data hiding in the sense how it would be used practically or in real time.

question : As I know data hiding would implemented in C++ to hide the actual data being used
behind the scenes in a programm suppose by declaring some datas **private in a class.**
when a C++ program is made and compiled ....consider an example of of some game,
the executable file (.exe or nay other executale in unix) would be given to the user?

so here what I am confused about?
now where is my data hiding?? when the user is using the executable(.exe) because I my opinion .exe cannot be read or opened by the user to see the contents of the file anyway..
even if **I declare all my variables public...still the data is hidden because the user just has the .exe file, which can't be read or manipulated by the user?**

Please suggest guys?? give some feedback where I am thinking wrong

Comment: totally incomprehensible

Comment: Ok, if you use data hiding in your program you are hiding your data from whom the functions or the user who is about to use it

Comment: @mukesh: what are you asking?

Comment: Data hiding is the concept on program development or code writing -- in another word.

Comment: Do we use data hiding to hide data from the user who is using my program (consider any game program) or its just for the functions so that only some functions can access a particular data??By the way sorry I about me ... being so misleading..

Comment: @mukesh: It's a concept of code level rather than application level. The 'users' there is other programmers instead of end users. BTW, I got a same confusion when I began to learn programming several years ago. :)

Comment: Thanks ,Rolling boy I got this buddy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data hiding is a way of **controlling dependency** of code in one part of an application **on code in another part of the application**.  That is, when one bit of code changes, should one or more other bits of code consequently need updating too?  As much as possible, you want the answer to that to be "no", because otherwise every little change you make to your program kicks off an avalanche of consequent changes before the program settles into a stable state where it will again operate properly.  To discourage a programmer from making their code arbitrarily dependent on any aspects of your class's implementation, and encourage them to only rely on a controllable part necessary for objects of the class to perform their intended function for the client, you can nominate the data and/or functions that the client is allowed to use: that's the "public" and/or "protected" interface.  Other things that you want to be able to change without the client code needing to care should be made `private`.

**This is all about development, and has nothing to do with the data the program handles at run-time, or protecting the program logic/data from snooping on by the end user**.

As an example, taskinoor appropriately cites a Date class that ensures the dates stored remain valid, so that client code can't just reach in and set the date to "31 Feb" or some other non-sensical value.  Further, without affecting clients, it is possible to change the data layout from say having three numbers store day, month and year to one number storing days since some reference day without affecting the clients (yielding a different performance profile - faster relative movements through dates but slower conversions to/from D/M/Y values).

Answer (score 2):

Data hiding refers to hiding data when someone's working with code which links/uses your code. It's used as a safety mechanism to ensure that the object is always constructed properly. It is also used as an abstraction method where users deal with the interface, but the underlying implementation can be changed "at will" without having to re-write any code which uses that code (for example, renaming a field name, or removing it completely).

Example:

A date class can hold the month, year, and day of the month. Depending on the month, there are different valid days of the month (30 for some, 31 for others, 28/29 for February). Also, there's only a certain number of valid months (could be taken care of using an enum). If you allowed a user to directly modify the day of the month field, there's no way to ensure that the object always holds valid data. Data hiding is used to prevent the user from directly accessing this data, and the user uses accessor methods to get/modify the field. These methods could have code to ensure that only valid data is entered.

Now if at a later date it's decided that representing the date as the number of days from January 1, 2010 is better. The user can still use the accessor methods as previously defined, which would translate the inputs/outputs appropriately.

Answer (score 2):

What is Data Encapsulation?
Data Encapsulation is binding the data and the functions that operate on the data in a single unit.
How do u implement Data Encapsulation?
By creating a Type. ex: Class, Structure etc.

What is Data Abstraction?
Data Abstraction is hiding the complexities of your type from the external world.
How do you implement Data Abstraction?
By using Access Specifiers. Ex: Public, Private, Protected.

Whom do the Access Specifiers hide data from?
The Access specifiers hide the data(by not providing them direct access to the data) from the users of the objects of the class/structure.

Consider your class in the Game as an separate unit, Which is used by the other functionality(source code) to perform some functionality. Usually, A class has a state and methods which perform operation on the state. The access specifiers hide members of the class from other source code (maybe classes or maybe structures). The other code can create objects of your class and can modify the state stores inside class data members through the public methods exposed by your class. Thus the Access specifiers provide a organised way of accessing class members.

Comment: Thank you, everybody I am clear about this ...from whom we are trying to hide the data....i.e Its not the user but instead its to hide it from another programmer,source code,function ....and thanks robert for mentioning the reading reference(book)

Answer (score 2):

Just give a simple example:

There's an ArrayList, which has a member--listSize denonting its size. Without Data Encapsulation or Data Hiding, a user of this ArrayList can set it to any value other than the number of elements.
Totally a disater.

Answer (score 0):

Data hiding is more in the form of hiding implementation from other programmers.

Simple example:

you have a class Car which contains a public method Drive
and a property DieselEngine, since you don't want the user to know about what engine is in the care you make DieselEngine private. Later you may replace the engine with a PetrolEngine else but since the user only can use Drive he doesn't have to change his code when you give him an update.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the term data hiding wrong. It is not hiding from the user, it means hiding from the other programmers.

For example, you are using a Stack class developed by another programmer. You have methods to push and pop value. But you don't know how the stack is actually implemented. It could have used an array, or it could have used a linked list to store the values. But you don't care about that details as a user of the class. You all know that you can push and pop to and from it. Here the internal data of stack is hidden from you. It's the responsibly of the developer of stack to maintain the internal storage, not yours when you are using that.

Answer (score 0):

You need allot more than anyone can type in this short forum.  I would suggest the book:

[Design Patterns Explained: A New Perspective on Object-Oriented Design (2nd Edition)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321247140)

It'll explain what the purpose of various elements of Object Oriented design are.  For instance, what is encapsulation and why do you use it?  And what is it you're actually encapsulating?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the implementation of any non-trivial data structure such as `std::vector<T>` or `std::map<K, V>` and you will immediately understand the benefit of data hiding: the client does not have to know how these data structures are implemented under the hood, he can simply *use* them.